# Photodiode - Turn Digital Input pin into 1 with little light Input

Tags: arduino, led, digital-logic, photodiode

Currently I am trying to work with a photodiode(SFH 203) that is supposed to detect very small amount of light.
Using the digital of an arduino  the photodiode cannot turn the pin to 1 due to the low level of light.
If I measure light with an anlaog pin I receive a value arnd 25-30.

Is there any way to bring the digital value to turn 1 using a small amount of light?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link to the datasheet, so we don't have to look for it? :)

Comment: Do u mean the datasheet for the photodiode?

Comment: http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic2/00101659_0.pdf/SFH%20203%20P,%20SFH%20203PFA,%20Lead%20(Pb)%20Free%20Product%20-%20RoHS%20Compliant.pdf

Comment: You show the photodiode forward biased- Usually a PIN photodiode is reverse-biased. Not sure why you have an LED in series.  If you don't care about speed you could reverse bias it with a large load resistor to ground and use a comparator to feed the digital pin.  Ideally, the reverse bias voltage would be higher than 5V, the datasheet gives a max value of 20V, so 12V might be OK if it's available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know, photodiodes work "backwards". That is, they create a current flow from the *cathode* to the *anode*, so in your schematic \$PD\$ is likely the other way around. This way, there's no light detection going on, I guess current will flow through the circuit at all times.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fATtUi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above schematic is my attempt at minimizing what's required for digitizing the PD output. It relies on the roughly-100 current gain (Beta) of the \$Q_1\$ transistor. \$10\mu A\$ should be enough to cause \$1mA\$ flowing through the collector-emitter junction. \$R_1\$ is simply a pull-up that says, that in dark conditions, the output will be HIGH. \$Q_1\$ then pulls it low-ish, when \$PD\$ gets illuminated enough.

To fine-tune the sensitivity threshold, you can try adjusting \$R_1\$ (or potentially replacing it with a potentiometer.)

Feel free to point out any mistakes I've made.

Comment: You've got R1 shorted in your schematic.

Comment: Thx for ur input! u r right pd is supposed to be reverse biased (mistake in drawing). Is it possible to use a transistor 7805 cv, as well?

Comment: @Sathees 7805 ain't a transistor. Its a voltage regulator.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet shows the photodiode's sensitivity as 9.5 uA per 1000 Lux.

Now I don't know what counts as "low light" to you, but let's try 10 Lux as a reasonable switching lu]evel - at that point, the photodiode will produce 95nA. Not very much ... how does it compare with the dark current? well that is specified as <10nA so 95nA is clearly above the dark current.

So we want to set the Arduino input to 1 (i.e. > 2.5V) with a current of 95nA. Neglecting the LED for the moment (there's no way it'll light up anyway) you can simply do this by replacing R1 with R = 2.5/95e-9 = 27 Megohms or so.

If the Arduino input pin leakage current is much greater than 10nA this won't be accurate, and if it's greater that 100nA it may not work at all, or the switching level may be something greatly different from 10 Lux, but you haven't posted the relevant datasheet so I can't check that.

(and as John D points out, connect the photodiode right way round!)

Comment: Thx! I just changed the resitor to 1Megaohm and the digital pin turns 1 providing light (20 lux); however even without light its analog value is at 400....well is there a pd u can recommend for its high sensitivity for white led light?

Comment: "analog value is 400" out of what? 1000? 4000? 65536? That's the dark current + Arduino pin leakage current. As for a better pd, now you know how to read the spec sheets so maybe you can find one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The SFH203, from looking at it's [datasheet](http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic9/00101656_0.pdf/SFH%20203,%20SFH%20203%20FA,%20Lead%20%28Pb%29%20Free%20Product%20-%20RoHS%20Compliant.pdf), has a `λS max` sensitivity range from 850-900nm, which is the [near-infrared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EM_spectrum.svg) range. It is less sensitive (up to 10% of max) at the visible light frequencies. There is a sensitivity chart included. So if you are using a blue LED for light, this can explain all of the loss in sensitivity. Use an 875nm near-IR LED and it will be much more sensitive.

Or if you are already using an 875nm LED and it's still not sensitive enough, then you'll have to use an op-amp such as one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=photodiode%20to%20microcontroller) to increase the gain.

In your circuit, the 10k resistor would limit the current in the (regular) LED to a value so small, it would probably not even emit light. Also, photodiodes generate a tiny *reverse current* when emitted to light, not forward conductance. Take a look at [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73732/how-to-use-sfh235-ir-photodiode-correctly) for another way to implement the photodiode.

Comment: thx for the link.
Do u think that an op amp would increase the sensity of the PD, as described
in the link?

Comment: Definitely. An op-amp's gain is typically set with two resistors. Depending on the performance of the chosen op-amp, gain can be 100,000x or more. (But at such large gains, noise and interference become issues.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the datasheet, the SFH 203 can only deliver around 10 microamperes of current.

Your LED alone will draw more current than that.

The Arduino input should be happy with the 10µA.  Remove your LED and R1.

If it still doesn't work, you may need to buffer the photodiode with a transistor to increase the current.

Comment: i tested it ..it doesnt work...the current is too low i guess..i need to test it with a transistor

Comment: And that would probably melt the diode if you are connecting it straight to 5V